# Celery redis reduce freqeuncy of BRPOP messages

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I'm running my worker with the following arguments `--without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat` with Redis as my celery broker

I can see my redis instance is frequently receiving messages (once a second) that look as follows:

```
1700056088.098427 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
1700056089.104080 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
1700056090.109984 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
1700056091.115298 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
1700056092.122189 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
1700056093.126348 [0 [::1]:45462] "BRPOP" "celery" "celery\x06\x163" "celery\x06\x166" "celery\x06\x169" "1"
```

This amount of traffic means I can't use certain free-tiers in cloud providers. Realistically I only need to run a single periodic task every hour (like a cronjob). Is there a way to reduce the frequency / interval of these messages?